# Save post in another table

Tags: save-post

I have problem in post date, Now when i add post at 17/1/2016 and modify this post to 18/1/2016. Now the old date are delete from table in database. So, I need to save old date in another table, when i add new post.

How can do that ?

Comment: The created date and modified date are both saved in the database, they are simply saved in different fields. And if you want to have a list of all the modification dates, you already have revisions for that.

Comment: but i delete revisions every day

Comment: If you are deleting the revisions, what use would a modification time list have?

Comment: i need to knew the original post date

Answer (score 1):

The original post_date is saved `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`.

And modification dates are saved on `post_modified_date` and `post_modified_date_gmt`. So you never lose your original creation date.

Comment: no, i lose original creation date.

Comment: I just checked one of my WordPress installations. Nothing gets lost.